# Problem with materialize grid (auto offset ?)

Tags: css, grid, materialize, offset, col

I'm currently working on a materialize project and I have a problem with the grids.

Indeed, my php generate 4 columns l-4 and the 4th go to the right side [as show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpv78.png)

```
<div class="row equipe">
        <h2><?php echo 'Equipe n°'.$data2[1].' '.$nomjeu2[0]?></h2>
            <?php 
                $stmt3->execute(array($data2[0]));
                while($infoplayer = $stmt3->fetch()){
            ?>
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
                <div class="card-panel">
                    <img class="responsive-img" src="<?php echo $infoplayer[2]?>">
                    <p><?php echo $infoplayer[1]?></p>
                    <?php if($infoplayer[3] != ''){?><a href="<?php echo $infoplayer[3]?>" class="waves-effect waves-light btn twitch" target="_blank">Twitch</a><?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

I don't really know what do to do here some help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Currently Materialize's grid is based on floats and it gets broken if cards are not of the same height. The card that is larger in the first row pushes the second row to the right. To avoid that it's easier to use custom styles with `flex` or `grid`.